# Infinite groups with finitely many elements of finite order.

Tags: group-theory

Give an example of an infinite non abelian group that has exactly 6 elements of finite order.

We have to search a group which have exactly 6 elements of finite order , so one of them is identity and among 5(remaining) there will be atleast one element of order 2 .
But I am not getting this fully.
I want a specific example which satisfies given assumption.

Comment: Try taking a direct product of a group of order $6$ with an infinite group.